# masking a series with a boolean array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This has given me a lot of trouble, and I am perplexed by the incompatibility of numpy arrays with pandas series. When I create a boolean array using a series, for instance

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
delta = np.percentile(x, 50)
deltamask =  x- y > delta
```

delta mask creates a boolean pandas series.

However, if you do

```
x[deltamask]
y[deltamask]
```

You find that the array ignores completely the mask. No error is raised, but you end up with two objects of different length. This means that an operation like

```
x[deltamask]*y[deltamask]
```

results in an error:

```
print type(x-y)
print type(x[deltamask]), len(x[deltamask])
print type(y[deltamask]),  len(y[deltamask])
```

Even more perplexing, I noticed that the operator < is treated differently. For instance

```
print type(2*x < x*y)
print type(2 <  x*y)
```

will give you a pd.series and np.array respectively.

Also,

```
5 < x - y
```

results in a series, so it seems that the series takes precedence, whereas the boolean elements of a series mask are promoted to integers when passed to a numpy array and result in a sliced array.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: `pandas` data structures are built on top of `numpy` arrays. `Series` do play ***somewhat*** nicely with `numpy` arrays, they're not really `numpy` arrays. Also, what do you mean by: _the series ignores completely the mask._? `deltamask` is all `False`, so the `Series` should not return any values.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other way around. Series do not respect array masks and arrays do not respect series masks.

Comment: I think `Series` do respect `numpy array` masks; check again. But numpy arrays don't seem to be taking `Series` masks (that's quite interesting, actually). But `x[deltamask.values]` does do the trick.

Comment: The issue is with numpy slicing. For some reason, it only accepts raw `ndarray` as a boolean mask. `x[deltamask]` gets interpreted as `x[[0, 0, ..., 0]]` rather than `x[[False, False, ..., False]]`, so the result is `[1, 1, ..., 1]`. I will look into this.

Comment: How does x[[0, 0, ..., 0]] get converted to x[1, 1, ..., 1]?

Comment: Because `x[0] == 1`.

Comment: The `False` elements of the Series get promoted to integer 0 for some reason. I get the following warning when I index `x[deltamask]`: `FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index`. This is a good indication of the fact that numpy devs are aware of the issue and have a fix coming.

Comment: As for the comparison issue, that is because of Python. If RHS for `<` is a subclass of LHS, `__gt__` is invoked on RHS instead of `__lt__` on LHS: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__. Basically, the subclass always has priority.

Comment: I will turn my comments into an answer once I hear back from the numpy mailing list.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know about the gt and lt methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fancy Indexing**

As numpy currently stands, fancy indexing in numpy works as follows:

1. If the thing between brackets is a `tuple` (whether with explicit parens or not), the elements of the tuple are indices for different dimensions of `x`. For example, both `x[(True, True)]` and `x[True, True]` will raise `IndexError: too many indices for array` in this case because `x` is 1D. However, before the exception happens, a telling warning will be raised too: `VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a boolean instead of an integer will result in an error in the future`.
2. If the thing between brackets is **exactly** an `ndarray`, not a subclass or other array-like, and has a boolean type, it will be applied as a mask. This is why `x[deltamask.values]` gives the expected result (empty array since `deltamask` is all `False`.
3. If the thing between brackets is any array-like, whether a subclass like `Series` or just a `list`, or something else, it is converted to an `np.intp` array (if possible) and used as an integer index. So `x[deltamask]` yeilds something equivalent to `x[[False] * 7]` or just `x[[0] * 7]`. In this case, `len(deltamask)==7` and `x[0]==1` so the result is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

This behavior is counterintuitive, and the `FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index` it generates indicates that a fix is in the works. I will update this answer as I find out about/make any changes to numpy.

This information can be found in Sebastian Berg's response to my initial query on Numpy discussion [here](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2016-August/075908.html).

**Relational Operators**

Now let's address the second part of your question about how the comparison works. Relational operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) work by calling the corresponding method on one of the objects being compared. For `<` this is `__lt__`. However, instead of just calling `x.__lt__(y)` for the expression `x < y`, Python actually checks the types of the objects being compared. If `y` is a subtype of `x` that implements the comparison, then Python prefers to call `y.__gt__(x)` instead, regardless of how you wrote the original comparison. The only way that `x.__lt__(y)` will get called if `y` is a subclass of `x` is if `y.__gt__(x)` returns `NotImplemented` to indicate that the comparison is not supported in that direction.

A similar thing happens when you do `5 < x - y`. While `ndarray` is not a subclass of `int`, the comparison `int.__lt__(ndarray)` returns `NotImplemented`, so Python actually ends up calling `(x - y).__gt__(5)`, which is of course defined and works just fine.

A much more succinct explanation of all this can be found in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).