# Indexing an array with a logical array of the same shape in Python

Tags: python

I would like to be able to do:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[[True, True, False]]
>> array([1,2])
```

I just can't find the simple way how... Thanks!

Comment: so you want to remove elements from list `a` based on another array of booleans?

Comment: Did this not work for you?

Comment: I take it you're using `numpy` here - if so - you may want to add the tag - if not - you've got the answer for a 1D solution via `itertools.compress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` and the mask are truly Python arrays, then you can do a simple list comprehension:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
mask = [True, True, False]
[a for a, m in zip(arr, mask) if m]
```

If you are OK with additional imports, you can use @moses-koledoye's suggestion of using `itertools.compress`.

If on the other hand you are using `numpy`, as the final output of `array([1,2])` suggests, you can just do the indexing directly:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
mask = np.array([True, True, False])
arr[mask]
```

Note that mask has to be an actual `np.boolean` array. You can not just use a Python list like `[True, True, False]`. This is because `np.array.__getitem__` checks if the input is exactly another array. If not, the input is converted to integers, so you end up effectively indexing with `[1, 1, 0]` instead of a mask. You can get a lot more details on this particular tangential issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39168021/2988730

Comment: Thank you. The issue was that my boolean array was a list and not a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

There's [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> mask = [True, True, False]
>>> list(compress(a, mask))
[1, 2]
```

---

If you're using *numpy*, you can slice directly with the mask:

```
>>> np.array(a)[np.array(mask)]
>>> array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and list comprehension.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [True, True, False]

c = [i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j]
```

Comment: this is exactly what `itertools.compress` does

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm not really familiar with `itertools.compress`, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

You can play with built-in `filter` and `map`

```
k = [True, True, False, True]
l = [1,2,3,4]

print map(lambda j: j[1], filter(lambda i: i[0], zip(k,l)))
```

Comment: Looks pretty enterprisey to me.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, I actually thought of using `filter` only because thats the point of the bool lists, but couldn't get to a solution .. the wrapping `map` made it to wordy. I was just playing with code though

Comment: Never hurts to do that. I usually end up trying to break out the fancy stuff as well whenever I have a problem like this. Every once in a while the fancy solution actually turns out best, so its always worth getting the practice.